# "Bizchus Avrohom ovinu". Why is it said as a response to “bircas kohanim”?

Tags: tefilla, avot-patriarch-fathers, birchas-kohanim

Why do some answer the *bircas kohanim pesukim* with “*kein yehi rotzon bizchus Avrohom ovinu*” etc. How does the “*bizchus*” phrase help?

Comment: Avrahom = Chesed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sefer Darash Av volume 4 
http://hebrewbooks.org/2985
says as follows.

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2985&st=&pgnum=20&hilite=

> There is a Medrash in Breishis Rabba 43 that says מהיכן זכו ישראל
>   לברכת כהנים ר׳ יהודה ור׳ נחמיה ורבנן רי״א מאברהם כה יהיה זרעך כה תברכו
>   את בני ישראל, ר׳ נחמיה אומר מיצחק שנאמר ואני והנער נלכה עד כה, לפיכך
>   אמר המקום כה תברכו את בני ישראל, ורבנן אמרי מיעקב שנאמר כה תאמר לבית
>   יעקב וכנגדו כה תברכו את בני ישראל.
>
> והנה המאמר הזה הוא מקור למנהג חאשכנזים בכמה קהלות כי בכל יום בשעה
>   שהש״ץ בתפלתו בקול רם אומר ברכת כהנים אז על הברכה הראשונה יברכך ה׳
>   וישמרך, הנה כל הקהל עונים ואומרים כן יהי רצון בזכות אברהם, ועל הברכה
>   השניה יאר ה׳ פניו אליך ויחנך, עונים ואומרים הקהל כן יהי רצון בזכות
>   יצחק. ועל השלישית ישא ה׳ פניו אליך וישם לך שלום, עונים הקהל כן יהי
>   רצון בזכות יעקב,
>
> ומנהג אשכנזים הזה יסודתו בהררי קודש מדברי המדרש הנ״ל דתפסי עלמא דברי
>   כולם וחלקו השלשה ברכות לשלשה אבות ואולי ס״ל דר"י ור״נ ורבנן לא פליגי
>   כלל אלא דר״י אמר דברכת כהנים זכו ישראל מאברהם וזהו הברכה הראשונה ור׳
>   נחמיה דאמר מיצחק היא הברכה השניה ורבנן דאמרי מיעקב כוונתו לברכה
>   השלישית

Further on these pages

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2985&st=&pgnum=21

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2985&st=&pgnum=22

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2985&st=&pgnum=23

he explains how each Bracha is tied in to that particular one of the Avos.

Comment: This only answers the first question.