# Why do we say כן יהי רצון in response to each blessing of Birkat Kohanim?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, birchas-kohanim

In most congregations (as far as I know), when the *chazzan* recites *Birkat Kohanim* (Priest's blessing) as part of the repetition of Shmoneh Esreh, after each of the 3 blessings, the congregation responds כן יהי רצון . What is the origin of this expression? Since it's a blessing (true, it doesn't have the format of a "standard" blessing (*shem umalchut*)) shouldn't we say אמן, instead, or perhaps, both?

Also, I noticed that when the *Cohanim* duchen, the cong. responds just אמן. Why the difference?

I am dealing with Nusach Ashkenaz in a shul outside Israel, as in Israel, they duchen every day.

Comment: Note that, in some congregations, the response is "_amen_" to each line when the _chazan_ says it also.

Comment: @msh210 See edits. I have heard "amen" in a few, but it seems to be the minority. In either case, I am curious about the origin and reason for this expression.

Comment: @msh210, have you heard אמן in non-Chabad kehillot outside of duchaning?

Comment: @DanF You haven't expressed that there is differences in custom. It may be worth noting that or at least noting what custom you are working in.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt, I don't recall for certain but tend to think so. But certainly _Chabad_ says it.

Comment: @msh210 Further, in some customs the practice is only to respond [whatever it is you respond] once, after the final line.

Comment: Note the Chazzan's "Kohanim" piece when there is no duchening is not itself a blessing. It is a prayer that God bless us with the blessings that the Kohanim gave, with an accompanying proof-text describing the alluded to blessings.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9619/759

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27850 (Also, I get the sense that this is an exact duplicate of a question I have seen on MY before).

Comment: @DoubleAA The question you linked has some "tangential" aspects. It doesn't address the origin of the expression or why there is a difference in protocol between chazan's reading & duchenin' based on Nusach Ashkenaz practice.

Comment: Perhaps it's to commemorate the Amen of actual Birchat Kohanim, while still distinguishing it from the real deal...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [כף החיים](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41181&st=&pgnum=161) explains this as follows:

Birkat Kohanim when recited by the priests is a blessing of the priests to the the congregation; thus, the appropriate response, as it is with all blessings, is אמן.

However, when recited by the chazzan, there is a difference of opinion on how the Birkat Kohanim should be viewed.

Some still see it as a ברכה, and hence their custom is that the congregation responds with אמן. (This is the chabad custom btw.) Whereas others argue that when recited by a non-kohen, the birkat kohanim cannot be seen as a blessing (this is strictly the domain of priests); rather it is considered to be a *prayer*, בקשה, of the chazzan on behalf of the congregation, and therefore, they respond with כן יהי רצון as is the customary response to a prayer.

Comment: Vote pending source, esp. for the claim of כן יהי רצון as is the **customary** response to a prayer. I'm curious what he means by "prayer" within this context. This is the only place in davening that I hear this response. Every other place is "Amen" (except for responsive readings like Kaddish or Kedusha, but that is not really a "response".)

Comment: @DanF added source

Comment: +1 as "promised". Quite interesting. I will prob. have to raise a follow-up M.Y. question on what he says about duchening. He says that since the kohanim made a *bracha* before duchening, we answer "Amen". I understand that we answered "Amen" after "Be'ahava", the actual bracha. But, the phrases are not in the form of a bracha!

Comment: @DanF: He says this in the source I quote? I don't see that there.

Comment: I had to read par. 15 again. I mistranslated the intent of the term "lashon bracha", which I initially translated as the **format** of a bracha (i.e. having *shem umalchut*). On second reading, I don't think that's what Kaf Hacha'im meant. Although the term is ambiguous, so, I'm not 100% sure. Your opinion?

Comment: Bracha here refers to blessing the Jewish people not God, so the concept of shem u'malchus is not applicable at all. לשון ברכה (here) means 'in a way of bracha' as opposed to bakasha.

Answer (score 4):

[Mishnah Berurah 127:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.127.10?lang=bi) explains that it is because the *chazzan* is not actually blessing the congregation, which only the *kohanim* do. Instead, he is requesting of G-d that He bestow those blessings on us. As such *ken yehi ratzon* (may it be His will) is the appropriate response, rather than the typical *amen* response to a blessing.

Comment: While this is fine, quoting some earlier sources would add more strength to this post. See the quotes at the end of the Beit Yosef which all (and so rules the the Shulchan Arukh) say not to say Amen, and the gist is more like "say one kein yehi ratzon at the end if you want or you can say nothing too"